# i am stuck in a infinte tp loop what can i do

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am stuck in an infinite tp loop and I don't know where the command block is and I also tried the server trick but It didn't fix it so what can id do now?

Comment: Welcome to arqade.se! Take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance. I definitely think that the question linked by Timmy will help you, so check it out. Don't forget to check most of the answers, not only the accepted ones, as there is differents ways to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `testForBlock` command to search where the command block is placed (well, this command was then removed in Minecraft Java 1.13).

The syntax of the above commands:

```
/testForBlock <position: x y z> <tileName: Block> [dataValue: int]
```

Or you could use `gamerule` command to disable command blocks in the map completely.

Command:

```
/gamerule commandBlocksEnabled false
```

Comment: I don't know where the command block is  and I don't play on bedrock

Comment: The question is tagged `minecraft-java-edition`, the `commandBlocksEnabled` gamerule is only in Bedrock edition